# Millisecond timestamp (13 digits) in Arduino

Tags: programming, c

How can I store a 13 digits int in Arduino?

For example, current timestamp is: 
1500666822235

An uint32_t can only hold 10 digits max.

64 bits integer does not seem to be supported on RFduino.

Comment: Where they come from? As strings, sequence of bytes ...?

Comment: They're timestamps of sensor logging application (accel, gyro). It comes from combining millis (uptime) and RTC (absolute time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**18446744073709551615**
That 20 digits. It is the maximum value of a `uint64_t`. Even the Arduino Uno can use the `uint64_t`. Perhaps the `Serial.print` does not support it, but the compiler supports it.

Which processor does your RFduino have ?

Where does the timestamp come from ? Perhaps you are asking the wrong question. Perhaps this is a [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 3):

> How can I store a 13 digits int in Arduino?

create a multi-byte type.

a 40-bit (32+8 bits), or a 96-bit (32+32+32) would hold a ton.

or BCD.